# Jpanel doesn't react when pressing ActionListerner

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

So I have made a GUI which is pretty simple looking similar to this:

[image]

Where I simple do

- Open for browse a music file
- Play for play the music
- Stop for stop the music.

Pretty simple thing but having some issues with make a JFileChooser. so what I did was using a simple GUI:

```
    btnOpen = new JButton("Open");
      btnOpen.setBounds(6, 71, 75, 23);
      pnlSound.add(btnOpen);

fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

  btnOpen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == btnOpen) {
     SampleJFileChooser();
```

and having a method that does the JFileChooser:

```
public void SampleJFileChooser(){

  JFileChooser jFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
  jFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("C:/Users/Balling/Desktop"));

  int result = jFileChooser.showOpenDialog(new JFrame());


  if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   File selectedFile = jFileChooser.getSelectedFile();
   System.out.println("Selected file: " + selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
  }
 }
```

but now the problem is, whenever I press the button Open, Nothing happends. and by that nothing JFileChooser pops out and I have been trying to have other sample code for JFileChooser but nothing. still the same issue. which means nothing comes up when pressing the Button.

What could be wrong?

Also I created this thread for the Audio, if I now can get it to work. how do I make so it reads the song and plays it? Is there special methods for it?

EDIT: I by accident removed a thread that had the same post and couldn't undeleted it so I re-try with this thread.

Comment: use `jFileChooser.showOpenDialogue` method

Comment: I tried to do this `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == btnOpen) {
     JFileChooser jFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
     jFileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    }` but still nothing.

Comment: Try `jFileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);` or provide a reference to the frame the button belongs to. I assume that since you're setting a new frame as the parent for the dialog, the dialog will be invisible due to its parent being invisible.

Comment: @Thomas now im not really with you? What do you mean :O?

Comment: Did you debug the `actionPerformed()` code? It could be that `e.getSource() == btnOpen` returns false (maybe you're recreating the button etc.)

Comment: @WeInThis What I mean is: the dialog will be placed relative to the parent (if there is one) and when you create a new (initially invisible) frame as the parent it could interfere with the position calculation and the dialog might not be visible. That's just a guess though since I never dug that deep into how the dialogs are displayed/positioned.

Comment: Tried to debug the ActionPerformed but it doesn't let me come there, which means it doesn't reacts when pressing the button.

Comment: I edited abit in the thread

Comment: Well, that leads to the assumption that the button you're clicking is not the button you're adding the action listener to. Please check and debug your code (note that we can't do that for you).

Comment: Hmm, Thats could mean I have missed something to add? Could that be a possibilty ?

Comment: That edit (the added `Start()` method, which btw violates the Java code conventions) seems to be totally irrelavant here.

Comment: Oh okey, I will remove it then:)

Comment: I dont understand, I made a program that has a Click aswell and works, but in this, it doesnt :O something is strange

Comment: I think im the stupiest guy ever. I was running the wrong Class all the time.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it...!!!
solution:-

```
 public class Solu implements ActionListener {
        File filename;
        JFrame wind = new JFrame("V");
        JButton btnOpen = new JButton("open");
        JPanel pnlSound=new JPanel();
public Solu() {
    wind.setSize(400, 500);
    wind.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    wind.add(btnOpen);
    btnOpen.setBounds(6, 71, 75, 23);
    pnlSound.add(btnOpen);
    wind.add(pnlSound);
    btnOpen.addActionListener(this);
    wind.setVisible(true);  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
    new  Solu();}
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(e.getSource()==btnOpen){
        JFileChooser filechooser = new JFileChooser();
        filechooser.setCurrentDirectory(new              File("C://Users//V//Desktop"));

         int result = filechooser.showOpenDialog(new JFrame());
          if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
           File selectedFile = filechooser.getSelectedFile();
           System.out.println("Selected file: " +selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
          }}}}
```

Comment: I got it to worked! I did something really stupid, I by accident runned a wrong class all the time. thats why :(

Comment: Just as a side note: simply posting code as a solution won't help in the long run  - you'd better help the OP understand what was wrong and what needs to be done to fix it. At least you should add some explanation to your code about what you did to make it run. This is for the OP and others to learn.